# How to use Stanford RegexNER in NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I know how to extract name entities with help of Stanford in NLTK.

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz') 
st.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())
```

However, I need to apply RegexNER as well. It's application in Java is easy and Stanford provided an example [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html).

However, I could not find any sources that explain how we can use it in NLTK as well. I will be thankful if you share your ideas and opinions.

Comment: Stanford NER isn't regex-based...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use NERClassifierCombiner for full function, you can try with the sample code below to specify the regexner.

```
class NERComboTagger(StanfordNERTagger):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.stanford_ner_models = kwargs['stanford_ner_models']
    kwargs.pop("stanford_ner_models")
    super(NERComboTagger,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  @property
  def _cmd(self):
    return ['edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner',
            '-ner.model',
            self.stanford_ner_models,
            '-textFile',
            self._input_file_path,
#            '-outputFormat',
#            self._FORMAT,
            '-ner.applyNumericClassifiers',
            'true',
#            '-ner.useSUTime',
#            'false',
            '-regexner.mapping',
            'edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/cn_regexner_mapping.tab',
            '-regexner.validpospattern',
            '^(NR|NN|JJ).*',
            '-regexner.ignorecase',
            'true']
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, one of the only ways to access the Stanford CoreNLP `RegexNER` Java class outside Java (i.e. in Python) is via this GitHub repo:

https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python

See my description, here:

https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python/issues/33

Basically, edit the stanford-corenlp-python `default.properties` file, enabling the regexner module and specifying the path to your custom named entities file:

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, regexner
# regexner.mapping = path_to_entities_file, e.g.
regexner.mapping = /home/victoria/projects/ie/entities.txt
```

You'll also need to edit the stanford-corenlp-python `corenlp.py` file, updating your paths to your locally-downloaded Stanford CoreNLP *.jar files ...